# How to make one class' generic type another's which has no child parent relationship with former?

Tags: java, generics

So I have an interface like:

```
public interface INotifier<T,G>{
   G getNotifications(){
    //does something   
    }
}
```

There are 2 other subclasses which implement the interface and have different generic types for G.

And another class which consumes the getNotification method like this:

```
public class Orchestrater<K>{
   K notifications = notifier.getNotifications();
}
```

I want to deduce K as the same type as G. But I dont have Orchestrater as a parent class or a subclass of INotifier to conclude that via reflection? Any idea how to do that?

Comment: `notifier.getNotifications();` doesn't even have the same signature as the interface (no arguments are passed). Either there's a superclass no-arg method, or your design is off. Is there some other code we can see?

Comment: Sorry my bad! Corrected it. I just converted my code to this, its confidential code. So I cant reveal. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be straightforward to have the same formal parameter for the `INotifier#getNotifications(T)` return type as the one for your `Orchestrator<K>` generic type and it all depends on your `notifier` field declaration.

Here is a developped sample of your `Orchestrator` class:

```java
public class Orchestrator<K>
{
    private INotifier<Object, K> notifier;

    public K getOrchestratedNotifications() {
        return notifier.getNotifications();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate ! That helps. :)

Comment: Glad to be in help :)